# Sliding window using the slider library

Tags: slider, rolling-computation, beta

I was able to replicate for my own data

using the code from tidy finance with R , where they did it with CRSP Data base. So I wished to know how to modify to get all the coefficients , rather than a single coefficient.

Thanks

```
estimate_capm <- function(data, min_obs = 1) {
  if (nrow(data) < min_obs) {
    beta <- as.numeric(NA)
   
  } else {
    fit <- lm(excess_returns ~ mkt_excess + hml + smb , data = data)
    # note that we take into account the coefficient of mkt_excess
    beta <- as.numeric(coefficients(fit)[2])
    
  }
  return(beta)
}

# rolling capm estimation
roll_capm_estimation <- function(data, months, min_obs) {
  data <- data |>
    arrange(date)

  betas <- slide_period_vec(
    .x = data,
    .i = data$date,
    .period = "month",
    .f = ~ estimate_capm(., min_obs),
    .before = months - 1,
    .complete = FALSE
  )
  
  return(tibble(
    month = unique(data$date),
    beta = betas
   
  ))
}
```

The result is as follows following the code. I was trying to modify to get all the betas that is the coefficients of all the variables rather than that of single variable.

Sectors.         Date.           Beta
industrials 2010-01-01  1.2083931
industrials 2010-02-01  1.2086042
industrials 2010-03-01  1.2098460
industrials 2010-04-01  1.2081268
industrials 2010-05-01  1.2031083
industrials 2010-06-01  1.2018917
industrials 2010-07-01  1.2109641
industrials 2010-08-01  1.2126419
industrials 2010-09-01  1.2085854
industrials 2010-10-01  1.2054154
industrials 2010-11-01  1.2044102
industrials 2010-12-01  1.2002095
industrials 2011-01-01  1.2047517
industrials 2011-02-01  1.2024800
industrials 2011-03-01  1.2018010
industrials 2011-04-01  1.2007981
industrials 2011-05-01  1.2007950
industrials 2011-06-01  1.1975802
...
1-18 of 1,716 rows

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change the output in the `estimate_capm` function. Let me stick to the original example in [Tidy Finance with R](https://tidy-finance.org/beta-estimation.html) but suppose you now also want to keep the estimated intercept of the rolling CAPM regression.

Thus, we adjust the function `estimate_capm` as follows:

```
estimate_capm <- function(data, min_obs = 1) {
if (nrow(data) < min_obs) {
regression_coefficients <- tibble(term = c("(Intercept)", "mkt_excess"), 
                                  estimate = NA)
} else {
fit <- lm(ret_excess ~ mkt_excess, data = data)
regression_coefficients <- broom::tidy(fit) |> select(term, estimate)
}
return(regression_coefficients)
}
```

Now, the function returns a tibble instead of a numeric variable. The only slight adjustment then is to remove `slide_period_vec` with `slide_period` to make sure that R can gather the output from the rolling window estimations. Thus, you only need

```
roll_capm_estimation <- function(data, months, min_obs) {
data <- data |>
arrange(month)

betas <- slide_period(
.x = data,
.i = data$month,
.period = "month",
.f = ~ estimate_capm(., min_obs),
.before = months - 1,
.complete = FALSE
)

return(tibble(
month = unique(data$month),
beta = betas
))
}
```

Then, you are done. Check the example from the book with the new output:

```
beta_example <- crsp_monthly |>
filter(permno == examples$permno[1]) |>
mutate(roll_capm_estimation(cur_data(), months = 60, min_obs = 48)) |>
drop_na()

beta_example |> unnest(beta)
```

For your personal example, you'll just have to make sure to adjust the desired output in the regression framework (as you did already) and the special case when an `NA` should be returned.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting the answer if the problem is solved for you! Have fun with Tidy Finance :-)